# When shall I call dimiss() or hide() in my Dialogs?

Tags: android, dismiss, android-dialog

I got this dialog snipet:

```
String message="This will be my message";

    AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alt_bld.setMessage(message)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {


             ProgressDialog dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(CombatActivity.this, "Loading", 
                     "Pushing OK...", true);


        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(MyFirstActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();



        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
    // Title for AlertDialog
    alert.setTitle("Nyertél.");
    // Icon for AlertDialog
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alert.show();
```

My question is:
Should i call .hide() or .dismiss() in any of these ?
The message text will be dynamicly read, and I dont want a separate instance for every shown dialog. I just want only one with updated messages.

So how and when should i call remove or dismiss ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you have to call `dismiss()`  before you call `finish()`, otherwise the dialog will remain in the background and can cause problem when you try to start other activities.

Comment: Why dismiss() and why not remove() ?

Comment: There's no such method as remove() in ProgressDialog

Answer (score 1):

In Android `hide()` a `AlertDialog` means simply making it disappear from screen. But, still it is retained and attached with the `Context`. So, you need to call `dismiss()` or `cancel()` method to detach from the `Context`. Otherwise, it will give a *"Leaked Window Error"*.